# jQuery 1.4.4 error "q.replace is not a function"

Tags: jquery, replace

I've made a script that automatically calculates the total price for a invoice.
Because I want to display the price with a comma instead of a point. I put `.replace('.',',');` on the javascript float value.

But now I'm getting a jQuery error.
The exact error is:

> Error: q.replace is not a function
>
> Source: http://****.nl/cms/pub/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
>
> Line: 101

And I use replace function as followed:

Someone puts a price in a HTML text field and I request that value with the following code:

```
var price = $(this).find('.product_price').find('input').val().replace(',', '.');
```

This line works, but I'm getting that strange jQuery error.

I hope that someone could help me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) will either return a string or `undefined`.  Here it is clearly returning `undefined`, as strings have a `replace` method.

My prediction is that your selector `find('.product_price').find('input')` has not found any elements; running `val` on an empty selection will return `undefined`.

Comment: So I need to check if the value is set?

Comment: Check if any values are found, then call `val` on the selection.